# Find the highest cell value in a row and return the adjacent cell value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to find the max ProductBlendPercentage value in each row and return the associated ProductBlendMaterial value in column E.

[image: Data snippet]

I wrote this formula and although it works, it seems incorrect to me.

=INDEX(A2:D2,0,MATCH(MAX(B2,D2),B2:D2,0))

Is there a correct way to achieve my goal?

Comment: How does it seem incorrect?

Comment: Other than a redundant `0` as a rows parameter I don't see why it would be "wrong" either. That being said, much simpler could be an `IF` function.

Answer (score 2):

As per the comment section, all seems fine since you have a working formula. However I'd suggest a much simpler solution to your problem:

```
=IF(D2>B2,C2,A2)
```